# Real time (near) Watson Speech to text for microphone audio bytes transcription using Javascript and Java websockets

Tags: speech-recognition, ibm-watson, speech-to-text, embedded-jetty, java-websocket

I am trying to invoke Watson Speech to text service from Javascript using browser microphone support with Java backend implemented using Jetty websockets. I am using Watson Speech to text Java SDK for service connectivity.

**Maven dependency**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.watson</groupId>
    <artifactId>speech-to-text</artifactId>
    <version>7.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is the code for it:

**JS**

```
(function helperDrawingFunctions() {
  CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.line = function(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    this.lineCap = 'round';
    this.beginPath();
    this.moveTo(x1, y1);
    this.lineTo(x2, y2);
    this.closePath();
    this.stroke();
  }
  CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.circle = function(x, y, r, fill_opt) {
    this.beginPath();
    this.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    this.closePath();
    if (fill_opt) {
      this.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,1)';
      this.fill();
      this.stroke();
    } else {
      this.stroke();
    }
  }
  CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.rectangle = function(x, y, w, h, fill_opt) {
    this.beginPath();
    this.rect(x, y, w, h);
    this.closePath();
    if (fill_opt) {
      this.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,1)';
      this.fill();
    } else {
      this.stroke();
    }
  }
  CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.triangle = function(p1, p2, p3, fill_opt) {
    // Stroked triangle.
    this.beginPath();
    this.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);
    this.lineTo(p2.x, p2.y);
    this.lineTo(p3.x, p3.y);
    this.closePath();
    if (fill_opt) {
      this.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,1)';
      this.fill();
    } else {
      this.stroke();
    }
  }
  CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.clear = function() {
    this.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.clientWidth, this.canvas.clientHeight);
  }
})();


(function playButtonHandler() {
  // The play button is the canonical state, which changes via events.
  var playButton = document.getElementById('playbutton');

  playButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (this.classList.contains('playing')) {
      playButton.dispatchEvent(new Event('pause'));
    } else {
      playButton.dispatchEvent(new Event('play'));
    }
  }, true);

  // Update the appearance when the state changes
  playButton.addEventListener('play', function(e) {
    this.classList.add('playing');
  });
  playButton.addEventListener('pause', function(e) {
    this.classList.remove('playing');
  });
})();


(function audioInit() {
  // Check for non Web Audio API browsers.
  if (!window.AudioContext) {
    alert("Web Audio isn't available in your browser.");
    return;
  }

  var canvas = document.getElementById('fft');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var canvas2 = document.getElementById('fft2');
  var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');

  const CANVAS_HEIGHT = canvas.height;
  const CANVAS_WIDTH = canvas.width;

  var analyser;

  function rafCallback(time) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(rafCallback, canvas);

    if (!analyser) return;
    var freqByteData = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(freqByteData); //analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(freqByteData);

    var SPACER_WIDTH = 10;
    var BAR_WIDTH = 5;
    var OFFSET = 100;
    var CUTOFF = 23;
    var numBars = Math.round(CANVAS_WIDTH / SPACER_WIDTH);

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#F6D565';
    ctx.lineCap = 'round';

    ctx2.clearRect(0, 0, CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
    ctx2.fillStyle = '#3A5E8C';
    ctx2.lineCap = 'round';

    // Draw rectangle for each frequency bin.
    for (var i = 0; i < numBars; ++i) {
      var magnitude = freqByteData[i + OFFSET];
      ctx.fillRect(i * SPACER_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT, BAR_WIDTH, -magnitude);
      ctx2.fillRect(i * SPACER_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT, BAR_WIDTH, -magnitude);
    }
  }
  rafCallback();

  // per https://g.co/cloud/speech/reference/rest/v1beta1/RecognitionConfig
  const SAMPLE_RATE = 16000;
  const SAMPLE_SIZE = 16;

  var playButton = document.getElementById('playbutton');

  // Hook up the play/pause state to the microphone context
  var context = new AudioContext();
  playButton.addEventListener('pause', context.suspend.bind(context));
  playButton.addEventListener('play', context.resume.bind(context));

  // The first time you hit play, connect to the microphone
  playButton.addEventListener('play', function startRecording() {
    var audioPromise = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      audio: {
        echoCancellation: true,
        channelCount: 1,
        sampleRate: {
          ideal: SAMPLE_RATE
        },
        sampleSize: SAMPLE_SIZE
      }
    });

    audioPromise.then(function(micStream) {
      var microphone = context.createMediaStreamSource(micStream);
      analyser = context.createAnalyser();
      microphone.connect(analyser);
    }).catch(console.log.bind(console));

    initWebsocket(audioPromise);
  }, {once: true});


  /**
   * Hook up event handlers to create / destroy websockets, and audio nodes to
   * transmit audio bytes through it.
   */
  function initWebsocket(audioPromise) {
    var socket;
    var sourceNode;

    // Create a node that sends raw bytes across the websocket
    var scriptNode = context.createScriptProcessor(4096, 1, 1);
    // Need the maximum value for 16-bit signed samples, to convert from float.
    const MAX_INT = Math.pow(2, 16 - 1) - 1;
    scriptNode.addEventListener('audioprocess', function(e) {
      var floatSamples = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
      // The samples are floats in range [-1, 1]. Convert to 16-bit signed
      // integer.
      socket.send(Int16Array.from(floatSamples.map(function(n) {
        return n * MAX_INT;
      })));
    });

    function newWebsocket() {
      var websocketPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var socket = new WebSocket('wss://' + location.host + '/transcribe');
        //var socket = new WebSocket('wss://localhost:8440/Websocket/socket');
        //var socket = new WebSocket('wss://localhost:8442/events/');
        socket.addEventListener('open', resolve);
        socket.addEventListener('error', reject);
      });

      Promise.all([audioPromise, websocketPromise]).then(function(values) {
        var micStream = values[0];
        socket = values[1].target;
        console.log("reaches here!!");

        // If the socket is closed for whatever reason, pause the mic
        socket.addEventListener('close', function(e) {
          console.log('Websocket closing..');
          playButton.dispatchEvent(new Event('pause'));
        });
        socket.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
          console.log('Error from websocket', e);
          playButton.dispatchEvent(new Event('pause'));
        });

        function startByteStream(e) {
          // Hook up the scriptNode to the mic
            console.log("reaches here also!!");
          sourceNode = context.createMediaStreamSource(micStream);
          sourceNode.connect(scriptNode);
          scriptNode.connect(context.destination);
        }

        // Send the initial configuration message. When the server acknowledges
        // it, start streaming the audio bytes to the server and listening for
        // transcriptions.
        socket.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
          socket.addEventListener('message', onTranscription);
          startByteStream(e);
        }, {once: true});

        socket.send(JSON.stringify({sampleRate: context.sampleRate}));

      }).catch(console.log.bind(console));
    }

    function closeWebsocket() {
      scriptNode.disconnect();
      if (sourceNode) sourceNode.disconnect();
      if (socket && socket.readyState === socket.OPEN) socket.close();
    }

    function toggleWebsocket(e) {
      var context = e.target;
      if (context.state === 'running') {
        newWebsocket();
      } else if (context.state === 'suspended') {
        closeWebsocket();
      }
    }

    var transcript = {
      el: document.getElementById('transcript').childNodes[0],
      current: document.createElement('div')
    };
    transcript.el.appendChild(transcript.current);
    /**
     * This function is called with the transcription result from the server.
     */
    function onTranscription(e) {
      var result = JSON.parse(e.data);
      if (result.alternatives_) {
        transcript.current.innerHTML = result.alternatives_[0].transcript_;
      }
      if (result.isFinal_) {
        transcript.current = document.createElement('div');
        transcript.el.appendChild(transcript.current);
      }
    }

    // When the mic is resumed or paused, change the state of the websocket too
    context.addEventListener('statechange', toggleWebsocket);
    // initialize for the current state
    toggleWebsocket({target: context});
  }
})();
```

**Java**

```java
public class JettySocket extends WebSocketAdapter {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(JettySocket.class.getName());
    private SpeechToText speech;
    private RecognizeOptions recognizeOptions;
    private ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    @Override
    public void onWebSocketConnect(Session session) {
        System.out.println("Session opened!!");
        super.onWebSocketConnect(session);
        speech = new SpeechToText();
        System.setProperty("IBM_CREDENTIALS_FILE", "ibm-credentials.env");
    }

    @Override
    public void onWebSocketText(String message) {
        logger.info("message received - " + message);

        super.onWebSocketText(message);

        try {
            getRemote().sendString("message");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onWebSocketBinary(byte[] msg, int offset, int len) {
        logger.info("Byte stream received!!");
        super.onWebSocketBinary(msg, offset, len);

        ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(msg);

        this.recognizeOptions = new RecognizeOptions.Builder()
                .audio(stream)
                //.contentType("audio/wav")
                .contentType("audio/l16;rate=48000;endianness=little-endian")
                //.contentType("audio/wav;rate=48000")
                //.model("en-US_NarrowbandModel")
                .model("en-US_BroadbandModel")
                //.keywords(Arrays.asList("colorado", "tornado", "tornadoes"))
                //.keywordsThreshold((float) 0.5)
                //.maxAlternatives(3)
                .interimResults(true)
                .build();

        BaseRecognizeCallback baseRecognizeCallback =
            new BaseRecognizeCallback() {

              @Override
              public void onTranscription
                (SpeechRecognitionResults speechRecognitionResults) {
                  System.out.println(speechRecognitionResults);
              }
        };

        speech.recognizeUsingWebSocket(recognizeOptions,
                baseRecognizeCallback);

        // wait 10 seconds for the asynchronous response
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onWebSocketError(Throwable throwable) {
        logger.info("Session error!!");
        super.onWebSocketError(throwable);

        throwable.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void onWebSocketClose(int statusCode, String reason) {
        super.onWebSocketClose(statusCode, reason);

        logger.info("Session closed - " + reason);
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>TODO supply a title</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
         initial-scale=1.0">

      <script type="text/javascript">
         var uri = "wss://localhost:8442/transcribe";
         var websocket = null;
         var message = "";
         function openConnection() {
            websocket = new WebSocket(uri);
            //websocket.binaryType = "arraybuffer";
            websocket.onmessage = function (event) {
                var node = document.getElementById('fromServer');
                var newNode = document.createElement('h1');
                if (event.data) {
                    newNode.appendChild(document.
                            createTextNode(event.data));
                         node.appendChild(newNode);
                }
                else {
                    newNode.appendChild(document.
                            createTextNode("Image uploaded"));
                         node.appendChild(newNode);
                }
            };
         }

         function closeConnection() {
            websocket.close();
         }

         function sendMessage() {
            var msg = document.getElementById('messageText').value;
            websocket.send(msg);
         }

         function sendFile() {
             var file = document.getElementById('filename').files[0];
             var reader = new FileReader();
             var rawData = new ArrayBuffer();            
             reader.loadend = function() {}
             reader.onload = function(e) {
                 rawData = e.target.result;
                 websocket.binaryType = "arraybuffer";
                 websocket.send(rawData);
                 alert("the File has been transferred.")
             }
             reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
         }
      </script>

   </head>
   <body onunload="closeConnection();">
      <div>
         <p>Client Message: <input id="messageText" type="text"/>
            <input id="sendButton" type="button" value="Send"
               onclick="sendMessage();"/>
            <input id="connect" type="button" value="Connect"
               onclick="openConnection();"/>
         </p>
         <p>
            Client Upload: <input id="filename" type="file"/>
            <input id="uploadButton" type="button" value="Upload"
               onclick="sendFile();"/>
         </p>
         <div id="fromServer"></div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

With the above code, the audio bytes are sent successfully to the backend when spoken from the microphone. But when the data is sent to Watson STT, it returns with empty response like this:

**Response: **
{
  "results": [],
  "result_index": 0
}

This indicates to me that either the bytes are not encoded correctly or the configuration used for normalization of audio is incorrect.

If I try with this configuration, I get the following error:

**Java:**

```java
this.recognizeOptions = new RecognizeOptions.Builder()
    .audio(stream)
    .contentType("audio/l16;rate=48000")
    .model("en-US_BroadbandModel")
    .interimResults(true)
    .build();
```

> SEVERE: could not detect endianness after looking at the tail 0 non-zero byte string in a data stream of 8192 bytes. Is the bytestream really PCM data?
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: could not detect endianness after looking at the tail 0 non-zero byte string in a data stream of 8192 bytes. Is the bytestream really PCM data? at com.ibm.watson.speech_to_text.v1.websocket.SpeechToTextWebSocketListener.onMessage(SpeechToTextWebSocketListener.java:128)

The above error is from the Watson STT SDK which indicates there is an issue with the way the audio bytes are transferred to the STT service API.

I have tried with different variations of configuration like changing sample rate, voice models but nothing seems to work. The same config seems to work perfectly with Google Speech to Text and I get the transcript in the response. I have done that referring to the sample provided in the below Google tutorial.
[Google STT tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/speaking-with-a-webpage/index.html?index=..%2F..index#1)

Please help with this issue and recommend a solution to fix it.

Comment: any idea how to change currrenttime of audio played through buffer?

Comment: Regarding the not detecting endianness issue.. this is exactly what happens if you are sending silence.  Note that on some platforms, i.e. macOS, if you don't have access to the microphone (for security reasons) the APIs will not fail but will give you silence.

Answer (score 0):

Per [Watson Speech To Text documentation](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/speech-to-text):

> The service automatically detects the endianness of the incoming audio...

Not sure why it fails in your case, but you can always set the endianness explicitly by adding it to the content type: `audio/l16;rate=48000;endianness=little-endian`.

**Update** regarding your sample file:

These are the parameters of the file that you provided

```
$ soxi /run/shm/8_Channel_ID.wav 

Input File     : '/run/shm/8_Channel_ID.wav'
Channels       : 8
Sample Rate    : 48000
Precision      : 24-bit
Duration       : 00:00:08.05 = 386383 samples ~ 603.723 CDDA sectors
File Size      : 9.27M
Bit Rate       : 9.22M
Sample Encoding: 24-bit Signed Integer PCM
```

This is what is should like

```
$ soxi /run/shm/16bit_test.wav 

Input File     : '/run/shm/16bit_test.wav'
Channels       : 1
Sample Rate    : 48000
Precision      : 16-bit
Duration       : 00:00:01.50 = 72000 samples ~ 112.5 CDDA sectors
File Size      : 144k
Bit Rate       : 768k
Sample Encoding: 16-bit Signed Integer PCM
```

Your file has 24-bit samples, while Whatson expects 16-bit. And the number of channels of your file is 8 - while Watson is said to downmix multi-channel audio to one-channel I would still try to convert manually first.

Comment: Right, i tried setting the endianness explicitly to both little-endian and big-endian but neither worked.

Comment: What is the error message after setting the endianness explicitly?

Comment: I don't get an error after setting endianness. But the response is empty, as mentioned in the question.

Comment: Try to run the Java code without the JavaScript parts. For example, use `FileInputStream` directly and see if that works. If it does, the the problem is in the data transport between Java and JS.

Comment: That works. I mean, I've sent .wav files in byte format. The issue looks to be the difference in the way the data is sent and the one expected by Watson STT. Probably related to audio config (sample rate, sample size, etc) but I'm not able to figure out.

Comment: If you provided a sample audio file, that would help a lot.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. You can download and use any of the files provided in the below link. [Sample Wav files](http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/Documents/AudioFormats/WAVE/Samples.html)

Comment: They're all in different formats. Can you specify exactly which one you were trying to transcribe?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Please use from this link:
http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/Documents/AudioFormats/WAVE/Samples/Microsoft/8_Channel_ID.wav

Comment: Updated my answer. TLDR: your file has 24-bit samples, while Watson expects 16-bit.

Comment: Finally found a way around proxy to share the file. Here is a valid one:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsPujkFiVOW3anQYyrJhgKnVI6M?e=kOetwN

Comment: Wait, I thought you were using _wav_, not _flac_? If it's the latter, then your Watson setup is wrong, and you should use `audio/flac` instead.